# React: get coordinates with offsetX/Y on click, will change on resize

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, positioning

I'm trying to create a simple project where the user will click on an area of the screen and depending on the stored coordinates it will return  a message .

The area is a background image that will move with the mouse by having backgroundPosition change dynamically with the mouse position, so the mouse stays on the center, the picture moves without need of scrolling.

The issue is that depending on the screen size, the coordinates from offsetX are different, so if i assign coordinates for the user to click upon it's likely that nothing will be triggered

how can i make sure that my coordinates are always the same, no matter what screen size?

```
import Navbar from "./Navbar";
import { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import cityBackground from "./s020gwdtsen31.png";
import skyBackground from "./11005249.jpg";

export default function Main() {
  const [screenX, setScreenX] = useState(350); //350
  const [screenY, setScreenY] = useState(100);
  const [clickX, setClickX] = useState(0);
  const [clickY, setClickY] = useState(0);
  const [screenSize, setScreenSize] = useState(0);

  useEffect(() => {
    document.body.style.overflow = "hidden";
    if (window.innerWidth > 300 && window.innerWidth < 450) {
      setScreenSize(6);
    } else if (window.innerWidth > 450 && window.innerWidth < 650) {
      setScreenSize(4.5);
    } else if (window.innerWidth > 650 && window.innerWidth < 1000) {
      setScreenSize(2);
    } else if (window.innerWidth > 1000) {
      setScreenSize(1.2);
    }
    console.log(
      "current ScreenSize:",
      screenSize,
      " width:",
      window.innerWidth
    );
  }, [window.innerWidth]);
```

this useEffect is to ensure that the entire page is showed when the screen is resized, by applying a multiplier depending on specific breaks

```
  return (
    <>
      <Navbar />
      <div
        onMouseMove={(e) => {
          setScreenX(e.clientX);
          setScreenY(e.clientY);
        }}
        
      >
        <div
          style={{
            backgroundImage: `url(${skyBackground})`,
            position: "absolute",
            zIndex: "-2",
            minWidth: "100vw",
            minHeight: "100vh",
            backgroundPosition: "center",
            backgroundPositionX: `${-screenX / 10}px`,
            overflow: "hidden",
          }}
        ></div>
        <img
          scr={cityBackground}
          onClick={(e) => {
            const { width, height } = e.target.getBoundingClientRect();
            const { offsetX, offsetY } = e.nativeEvent;
            setClickX(Math.round((offsetX / width) * 100));
            setClickY(Math.round((offsetY / height) * 100));
            // console.log(Math.round((offsetX / width) * 100) );
            // console.log(offsetX, offsetY);
          }}
          style={{
            position: "absolute",
            minWidth: "100vw",
            minHeight: "100vh",
            background: `url(${cityBackground})`,
            backgroundPosition: "center",
            backgroundPosition: `${-screenX * screenSize}px ${-screenY * 2}px`,
            transform: `translate3d(0, 0, 0)`,
          }}
        />
      </div>
    </>
  );
}
```